# MySQL unir tablas seleccionando el valor el valor mínimo de dos de sus atributos

Tags: mysql, join

Quiero mostrar la población más pequeña que la/s persona/s más jóven han visitado y uno varias tablas de una base de datos

```
select ci.name, ci.population, per.personname, per.age, vis.dateArrived
from country co
inner join city ci
    on co.code = ci.CountryCode
inner join hasvisitedcity vis
    on ci.ID = vis.cityID
inner join person per
    on vis.personID = per.personID
```

pero quiero que sólo muestre la población más pequeña que la persona/s más jóven han visitado. Pero si pongo `min(per.age)` en la primera línea me sale mal el output. Me explico: el resultado que busco es:

```
Dordrecht | 119811 | Sean | 22 | 2000-06-20
```

Que aparece en la primera fila de la tabla si añado  `order by age` (esa es la población más pequeña que ha visitado la persona más joven). Pero si pongo 
 `min(per.age)` devuelve una única fila pero errónea:

```
Dordrecht | 119811 | Tom | 22 | 2002-02-11
```

Cuando en realidad el único Tom de la base de datos tiene 44 años siendo el mayor que ha visitado esa localidad.

Además creo que también habría que añadir algo equivalente a `min(co.population)`

Comment: A qué te refieres con que sale mal? Edita y muestra lo que estás obteniendo

Comment: si añado  `order by age` la primer fila en la tabla es: 

Dordrecht  | 119811  |  Sean  |  22  |  2000-06-20

y ese el que quiero que se muestre, pero sólo ese (la población más pequeña que ha visitado la persona más joven). Pero si pongo `min(per.age)` devuelve una única fila pero errónea:

Dordrecht  |  119811  |  Tom  |  22  |  2002-02-11

cuando en realidad el único Tom de la base de datos tiene 44 años

Comment: A esta consulta le faltan group by, si no, va a traer el min de toda la tabla, que no es lo que vos queres. pero sin ver las tablas y algunos datos dificil ayudarte...

Comment: puedo subir la base de datos en forma de archivo?si no lo he hecho es por que he visto preguntas similares (que no me han aclarado) y que parecía que no aportaban tablas, con la query de unir tablas parecía que obtenían respuestas

Comment: Lo puedes realizar usando métodos de agregación, de igual forma evalúa generar un ranking a partir de funciones de ventana....dale una vuelta http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-rank-function/

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]